# Data from UI updating with delay - ng-repeat (ngAnimate issue)

Tags: angularjs, web, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following problem and I would need some opinions about the possible causes/solutions of it.

I have a table with its body containing an ng-repeat

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="product in shoppingCart"> ... </tr>
```

with a delete button on each line:

```
<td class="total"><i data-ng-click="removeProduct(product, $index)" class="icon-remove-circle"> </i></td>
```

and the function:

```
removeProduct: function (removedProduct, index) {
     var _this = this;
     _this.$scope.shoppingCart.splice(index, 1);

     // + DELETE API Request
 },
```

The problem is that even if I do not wait for the API request response and the data in the model is updating immediately (the length and content of the shoppingCart object), the changes appear in the UI with a significant delay and not instantly as it should be.

EDIT: I just figured out that by removing angular-animate (ngAnimate) from the project, the problem is solved. The thing is that I am using angular-animate in the project and I cannot remove it.

Comment: Finally I used the fix from here https://gist.github.com/FGRibreau/9504619

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing, if I'm not wrong, is deleting an item from your shoppingCart list without even checking the response from your delete API. Possibilities are the API could even fail and the item gets deleted despite that. Perform the deletion based on the API response, maybe something similar to -

```
removeProduct: function (removedProduct, index) {
    var _this = this;
    $http.post('DELETE API').then(function(success) {
        _this.$scope.shoppingCart.splice(index, 1); 
    }, function(failure) {
        console.log("Error in deleting", failure)
    });
},
```

After you get the response from your delete API, depending on the response you could either update the cart(delete item from cart) or throw an error.